# Android hierarchyviewer load times

Tags: java, android

I've seen a lot of different tutorials of how to use the android hierarchy viewer.  In all of them the tutorial will have a picture of 3 circles colored green red or yellow, and 3 times, Measure, Layout, Draw.

I have 2 different applications and loading the hierarchy view with either I get n/a for all 3 of the times, and no dots.

Has anyone experienced this?  The device I'm running against is 2.2, is that to old for the times to load?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old.

I had the same problem and **running newer version of android emulator** solved the problem.